# Declined flags for subsequently edited posts and plagiarised answers

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

It seems there ought to be a way to respond to the moderator that declined a flag, however, I don't believe there is one (please, somebody let me know if I'm wrong but I completely understand why there wouldn't be). So, a couple of questions. Firstly, I flagged this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358141/how-to-work-with-two-update-panels-on-same-aspx-page/53568942#53568942) when it read

> i try this for 4 updatepanel , its work.

The answer was subsequently edited into something more useful after my flag, and the flag declined. Since too many declined flags are a bad thing, it seems there needs to be an alternate response, perhaps it could just be disputed or the flag discarded since the edit did make it wrong?

Secondly, I flagged this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012385/websocket-connection-to-ws-localhost8125-failed-error-in-connection-estab/53568814#53568814) because it:

> some browser's doesn't allow insecure websocket (ws) connections to localhost (only wss, so you should setup a TLS certificate for your local web/websocket server).

was a cut and paste from the highest voted answer to another (to my eye duplicate) question:

> Chrome doesn't allow unsecure websocket (ws) connections to localhost (only wss, so you should setup a TLS certificate for your local web/websocket server). However the same should work fine with Firefox

I'd like to understand why flagging that post as VLQ was wrong.

Comment: _The first one was subsequently edited to something more meanignful_.. Not **exactly**. If you see the edit link in the 1st revision in the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53568942/revisions), OP had simply missed formatting the code and it was not visible in the post

Comment: @SurajRao ah I see what you mean when I look at it in side-by-side. Unfortunately since I did not try to edit the post that code was not visible to me when I reviewed the answer.

Comment: If you don't downvote unnecessary answers then it does get hard to get rid of them.  Mods are not that keen on turning a single flag into a super-vote.  Understandably, if they do it just once then there's no end to "you didn't do it again" complaints.  Do what you can, don't hope for anybody else to do it for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The answer was subsequently edited into something more useful after my flag, and the flag declined.

That flag *probably* could've been marked helpful since it ended up getting reviewed by a moderator. It could've gone either way.

> I'd like to understand why flagging that post as VLQ was wrong.

Because VLQ doesn't mean "this answer was copied without following the rules on copying content", it means "this answer is irredeemably poor in such a way as to be unintelligible and unsalvageable". If you want to flag copied content, raise a custom flag stating so and pointing to the source. Don't pick a different flag that doesn't reflect your intentions or the nature of the post.

In fact, VLQ was probably a better choice than NAA for the *first* answer you flagged, even though NAA and VLQ are functionally equivalent as far as the backend is concerned.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, especially about how to flag answers like the second.